# product attribute setting image value store in witch data table in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

[image]

in that setting we set brands logo so i need to know that image store in witch data table

[image]

Comment: this depends on the module you are using. we can't help you here

Comment: You can try to do a search in all of the database by the name of one img you already added and see if you can find any reference.